# Why does Emmit Otterton scream about the Night Howlers just befor going savage?

Tags: character-motivation, animals, zootopia

In the scene where Judy and Nick visit Mr. Big's driver Mr. Manchas who

> goes savage

just after telling them about Mr. Otterton, a florist who had disappeared, who kept screaming about the Night Howlers before doing the same.

Later, we find out what Night Howlers are: a toxic flower that has interesting properties: animals who ingest it go savage.

The antagonists are using that flower to make it look like all predators are going wild, using a dart gun. From Nick's act (and the fact that the antagonists aren't surprised about the speed of the "effect") we know that the dart acts within a few seconds, and as soon as it hits, it starts acting, causing the animal to behave in a way comparable to Toothless in How To Train Your Dragon 2 (about a minute before Stoic's death), wimpering and rolling on the floor. This does not leave Mr. Otterton time to try to warn Manchas.

So why does he shout about them, if he hasn't been hit yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emmitt Otterton is a florist.

Duke Weaselton has been regularly stealing Night Howlers from stores.  The latest instance of this is during the chase scene early in the movie.  Probably, Emmitt was a previous victim and he knew the effects of the Night Howlers, and that anyone affected would have to be (temporarily) removed from society.

Basically, he figured out what was going on, at least partially, well before Judy.  The whole reason he was going to see Mr. Big was to see if the missing mammals had something to do with the mob, and Night Howlers were on his mind.

Comment: I thought that he was invited by Mr. Big, hence the limo. I thought at first it ws to do with the wedding, but that is a few weeks later...

Comment: @MarkGardner "Otterton is my florist.  He is like a part of the family.  He had something important he wanted to discuss, that's why I sent that car to pick him up. But it never arrived.."

Comment: But why scream at the driver?